# How to determine authenticated status on client side?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, csom

Do you know any syncronous way to get IsAuthenticated status for currentRequest in client side via javascript?

I can get current user via client model, but it will be asynchronous.

```
this.authenticationPending = true;
this.isAuthenticated = false;

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
   var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   this.website = context.get_web();
   this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
   context.load(currentUser);
   context.executeQueryAsync(
      Function.createDelegate(this, function ()
          {
             this.authenticationPending = false;
             this.isAuthenticated = this.currentUser.get_id() > 0;
          }),
          Function.createDelegate(this, function ()
          {
             this.authenticationPending = false;
             this.isAuthenticated = false;
          }));
}), "sp.js");
```

After that I can get status, but I need to get status synchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on a standard SharePoint page -- if so, you can use the `_spPageContextInfo` object's `userId` and `userLoginName` properties.

They come along for the ride when the page is rendered.

From my browser dev tools:

```
>_spPageContextInfo.userId
1337
>_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName
"somebody@somecompany.onmicrosoft.com"
```

If you're dealing with an anonymous user those two properties will both be `undefined` so you can make your checks accordingly.

Comment: The second way is using spsecuritytrimmedcontrol to surround client script block to initialize javascript variable with authenticated status.

Comment: Heads up that if the page is currently anonymous but you have NTLM setup and the user's browser can authenticate, the userId attribute will get populated when you call _spPageContextInfo.userId. This may lead to unexpected/undesired behavior.